# spring boot - tomcat server not starting with java 10

Tags: spring-boot, java-10

I am moving my elastic search spring boot(2.1.3) project from java 8 to java 10.

After solving all the compile time and runtime issues (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28984), the application finally seemed starting  but it does not start the Tomcat server. 
It prints following

```
2019-03-31 01:01:05.734  INFO 6735 --- [           main] run.Application                          : Starting Application on userlocal with PID 6735 (/Users/home/workspace-sts-3.9.7.RELEASE/demo10/target/classes started byuser in /Users/home/workspace-sts-3.9.7.RELEASE/demo10)
2019-03-31 01:01:05.736  INFO 6735 --- [           main] run.Application                          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-03-31 01:01:06.316  INFO 6735 --- [           main] run.Application                          : Started Application in 0.755 seconds (JVM running for 1.565)
```

If it was successful then 3rd line should be ( copied from the log of the java 8 version of the same application)

```
2019-03-31 01:03:09.810  INFO 6763 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@be64738
```

Can someone please give some high level idea why tomcat server is not starting with the java 10?

Please see the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo11</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo11</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>10</java.version>
            <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <lombok.version>edge-SNAPSHOT</lombok.version>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>projectlombok.org</id>
    <url>https://projectlombok.org/edge-releases</url>
</repository>
```

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
<artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
<version>1.3.0.Final</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
       <!--   <artifactId>transport</artifactId> -->
       <!--  <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>-->
       <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
```

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you post your **pom.xml** ?

Comment: Updated with pom.xml

Comment: Understood the issue. I was using wrong artifact id. I should have used spring-boot-starter-web as the artifactid instead of spring-boot-starter. Thanks. Now everythings works fine